# Firefox 4 and Keycode for special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, keycode

So in Firefox when i do a key combination like: SHIFT + "," which would equal "<" the key code comes back as '0'. Same thing is true for keys: "." ">" and many others.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can we see the code you are using?

Comment: just a event listening to keydown in jquery and trying to figure out if its key code so i can stop the event.

Comment: SHOW THE CODE! DO NOT EXPLAIN IT! Maybe caps will help:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836596/javascript-keyboard-shortcuts-for-web-application/5888756#5888756), if you use jquery already. And maybe see how they did it in those plugin.

**edit**

In jquery hotkeys there is object for mapping characters with shift:

```
shiftNums = {
"`": "~", "1": "!", "2": "@", "3": "#", "4": "$", "5": "%", "6": "^", "7": "&",
"8": "*", "9": "(", "0": ")", "-": "_", "=": "+", ";": ": ", "'": "\"", ",": "<",
".": ">", "/": "?", "\\": "|"
}
```

There are also lines:

```
character = String.fromCharCode( event.which ).toLowerCase();

var tmp = shiftNums[ character ];
```

This should help you. [Source code.](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/jquery.hotkeys.js) [About which.](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) BTW: source code of jquery hotkeys is such small so it wouldn't affect size of your scripts:)

Comment: Whats the property?  I don't need another plugin, I just need to prevent this one case.